# C# While Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop, infinite

I'm still learning the fundamentals of C# and I'm currently busy with some code which has got me stuck in an infinite loop.

```
   do
   {
        Console.Write("Please enter the Exam mark for student " + (index + 1) + ": ");
        Exam[index] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter the DP for student " + (index + 1) + ": ");
        DP[index] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Final[index] = (DP[index] + Exam[index]) / 2;

            index++;
    } while (DP[index] != 999);
```

The code doesn't break when I type 999.

Comment: Using a debugger, a problem like this can be fixed in less time it took to wrote the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You increase the index with 1 just before the `while` condition is checked. I guess the value is `0` on that index...

A solution can be to remember the previous value in a variable, or subtract one from the index:

```
    } while (DP[index - 1] != 999);
```

Another problem might be the use of a double, since it is imprecise, it doesn't always match to `999` if you entered that value. If you can, use `int` or `decimal`.

Comment: Or simply increase the `index` by using `while (DP[index++] != 999);` which will be executed AFTER the actual condition.